# Should I use Queue for sending email through 3rd party service

Tags: php, email, laravel, gmail, sendgrid

Laravel and Lumen provide a [Queueing](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/queues) mechanism for queueing tasks that take more processing so that the performance of web-app is not affected during busy times.

But when using 3rd party Emailing service like [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com), [Gmail](https://gmail.com).

**Should I queue Email Sending through 3rd party?** I don't know whether it'd take as much processing on my Laravel Web-App as self-hosted Email Sending does?

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on situation. 
Suppose you need to verify a user's email address so the verification email should be send in real time. Now another situation, you have to send a newsletter, so you can send it any time. So it totally depends on the importance of the email.

Here can read about different email types, https://www.mailjet.com/docs/email_types

Comment: Say its a newsletter which I can send at any time using 3rd party Email service. Does queueing here would benefit?